# expo eas build command failed at run gradle

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo, eas

I am new to React Native projects. I have been trying to bundle my app, I usually get an error about ./gradlew file so I decided to delete the Android and iOS folders and replace them, but after that I started getting this error:

```
536 actionable tasks: 536 executed
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_check] /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/res/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/drawable-mdpi/assets_check.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_check] /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/res/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/drawable-mdpi/assets_check.gif: Error: Duplicate resources
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 5m 49s
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

I have been trying to fix this. I searched for answers online but none are working. What can I try next?